# How to make swagger-ui show certain fields in JSON as required (using springfox-swagger2 & ui)

Tags: json, spring, rest, swagger, springfox

I am using springfox-swagger2 and springfox-swagger-ui version 2.5.0 dependencies to generate my JSON APIs and also using swagger-ui to show the JSON messages.

Currently swagger ui shows my JSON model with all the fields as optional. How can I specify certain fields to be required. Do I need to annotate any field in my POJO to state that it is required. 
I am not using any swagger annotations and relying on springfox to generate JSON from my POJOs.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use the 'required' attribute of the `@ApiModelProperty` annotation

```
public class LoginResponse {

    @ApiModelProperty(value="User's last name", required = true)
    String firstName;

    @ApiModelProperty(value="User's first name", required = true)
    String lastName;

    public LoginResponse(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName= firstName;
        this.deviceSecret = lastName;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
public ResponseEntity<XXX> getXXX(
        @RequestParam(value="id", defaultValue = "1234") @ApiParam(value="Some description of id", required = true) String id,
        @RequestParam(value="anotherField", defaultValue = "AR") @ApiParam(value="another Field", required = true) String anotherField) {
```

Using required=true or false in ApiParam annotation worked for me.